# vsrm.dev.azure.com is blocked by CORS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I was able to access vsrm.dev.azure.com API via $.ajax.get calls
i.e. https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/microsoft/***/_apis/release/definitions/****

Now I'm starting to get CORS error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/microsoft/***/_apis/release/definitions/***' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Comment: Exact same thing happened to me, turned out my personal access token had expired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ajax get` still work for me now without any error message. Since you did not share any code of yours, here I just provide you mine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#click").on("click", function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project name}/_apis/release/definitions/{id}?api-version=5.1',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("" + ":" + "{PAT token}"));
                },
            }).done(function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }).error(function (e) {
                var s = "error error error";
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

You can try with mine to see whether it is work for you.

---

**Update:**

I cover my `org name`, `project name`, `release definition id` and my `PAT token` in my script, please replace it with your available values.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work when I test it: https://jsbin.com/rizahaseye/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Quentin, you seems did not replace the available value there. I hide my org name, project name, and PAT in above script.

Comment: @Quentin, here is my .html executed result: https://imgur.com/a/kqLvS7Y